# MDX - how to exclude certain members in mdx

Tags: mdx

i'm wondering how to exclude certain members from one dimension that have links with other members from another dimension ... let's say i want to exclude clients (dim_clients) that have a status A OR a status B (dim_status).
I know how to crossjoin the two dimensions to obtain those clients but i can't figure out how to exclude them from my calculation since the EXCEPT function accepts two sets from same dimensionality but the ones i want to exclude are the result of a crossjoin operation, i can't use the except function

i want something like this :

```
SELECT Measure.MyMeasure ON 0 
FROM MyCUBE 
WHERE 
EXCEPT([DIM CLIENTS].[Clients], [EXCLUDED CLIENTS])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Measure.MyMeasure ON 0
FROM MyCUBE
WHERE
EXCEPT([DIM CLIENTS].[Clients], Filter({[DIM CLIENTS].[Clients]},[DIM_STATUS].CurrentMember IS [DIM_STATUS].statusA OR [DIM_STATUS].CurrentMember IS [DIM_STATUS].statusA))
```

I am not too sure what `[Clients]` is. I would use Members though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Extract()](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Extract.html) function to get the set of excluded clients with the right dimensionality:

```
where - Extract( { [EXCLUDED CLIENTS] }, [DIM CLIENTS].[Clients] )
```

Note the unary operator to perform the except operation.